# $f:(X,\tau) \mapsto (Y,\tau')$ is continuous and $ \tau'$ is T2 Why is $ \{p \in X\ f(p)=q\}=f^{-1}(\{p\}) $ closed?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:(X,\tau) \mapsto (Y,\tau')$ be continuous and $\tau' $ is Hausdorff.

$ \forall q \in Y$, we have that $\{p \in X\ f(p)=q\}=f^{-1}(\{p\})$ is closed

I don't know how to prove this. I wanted to use the Hausdorff's definition but I only have a point$ q \in Y$  to start with and Hausdorff requires 2 points, If I consider a second point p and disjoint open sets containing them, I don't know how to use the continuity of f. I know that if  $\{p\}$
were closed, then by the continuity the pre-image would be closed, but this only happens in the discrete topology, while the proposition is general.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{p\}$ is indeed closed. Let us show that its complement is open. Suppose $q \in Y \setminus \{p\}$. Then $q \neq p$ so there exist disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ in $Y$ such that $p \in U$ and $q \in V$. Now $V$ is contained in $Y \setminus \{p\}$ and it is an open set containing $q$. Hence $Y \setminus \{p\}$ is open.